# pass id from angularjs function to codeIgnite controller function

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

How to pass id from AngularJS function to codeIgniter controller function ??

```
$scope.edit = function(id)
    {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url: '',//how to go codeigniter controller function myfuc and send id.
             headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
        $scope.form = data;
        });
    };

public function myfuc(id)
{
   //here id
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate your problem , may be further code ?

Comment: yes I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  url: 'example.com/myfuc/id'
```

[read more](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html#passinguri)